# Using groovy to replace string with regex not working

Tags: regex, groovy, replace

I am trying to replace the following artLeadStr with "mj211f" using regex in groovy but does not seem to work. Please help.

Ex: result in error

```
def artLeadStr = "[JONES,MIKE - mj211f]"
def artLeadIdResult = artLeadStr.replaceAll([a-z](\S{5}))
System.out.println(artLeadIdResult)
```

Comment: Use a slashy string `.replaceAll(/[a-z]\S{5}/, "")`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/vbO6aJ).

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Is this a copy and paste error, or do you really not have `"` or `/` for the regexp inside `replaceAll()`?

Comment: with your way of writing, the code won't even compile. You can't just write `artLeadStr.replaceAll([a-z](\S{5}))` totally ignoring Groovy and Java rules and hope it would magically work

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response. But, I realized I didn't need regex after all as I was receiving a json object. See how I handled below.
 
Thanks for the help.

```
// Libraries used
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor;

def customFieldManager = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager();

// Retrieving object from a custom field. This is from a Jira template.
def requestApprover = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject("customfield_19792");
 
// Used for testing
//String empty = '{"keys":[""]}';
//String str = '{"keys":["DOE,JOHN - jd718w"]}';

String approver = "";

// Retrieving the field value from the object above.
String requestApp = issue.getCustomFieldValue(requestApprover);

// using JsonSlurper to parse json object and obtain the value
def jsonSlurper1 = new JsonSlurper();
def object = jsonSlurper1.parseText(requestApp); 
String result = (object.keys[0]);
 
if (result != ''){
    String[] str2;       
    str2 = result.split('-');
    approver = str2[1].trim();
    println(approver);    
}else{
    println("empty");
    approver = "pp210q";
    println(approver);
}
```